# Listing permissions of a DriveItem no longer return correct results

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm facing a problem this morning with listing permissions of a DriveItem, in my application but also in the graph explorer:

It returns a well formated json (with HTTP code 200) as before but it displays only **owner permission** and links.

Yesterday, it returned correctly all the permissions, which I can see in the onedrive web interface.

I did not play with scopes and application rights.

Here are some info about the request:

```
client-request-id: d2b9b57c-270b-4516-8e7e-5d16350da4f2
request-id: d2b9b57c-270b-4516-8e7e-5d16350da4f2
```

route:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b%21B81-V8mIJEGu..../items/01ZE2EVBYR..../permissions
```

result:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives('b%21B81-V8m...')/items('01ZE4F...')/permissions",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "OEJBNjA4Q0M...",
            "roles": [
                "write"
            ],
            "link": {
                "scope": "anonymous",
                "type": "edit",
                "webUrl": "https://..."
            }
        },
        {
            "grantedTo": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "mpa@s...",
                    "id": "34677232...",
                    "displayName": "..."
                }
            },
            "id": "aTo...",
            "roles": [
                "owner"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone explain me why ?

Thanks

Comment: OK... it seems that, from today, users with which I shared a folder are no longer visible in permissions list (they are not listed with the "grantedTo/user/..." json structure) and were grouped around a shared link.

This wasn't the behaviour before and it's not only related to me as all my co-workers ran into the same problem.